# Unable to get refresh token in salesforce OAuth

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oauth-2.0, salesforce

I am following [this link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_refresh_token_flow.htm&type=5) in order to get refresh token in salesforce. My code look like

```
Dim createClient As New HttpClient
Dim restQuery As String = "https://login.salesforce.com?grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=" & strKey & _
                "&client_secret=" & strSecret & "&refresh_token=" & refreshToken
Dim request = New HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, restQuery)
Dim response = Await createClient.SendAsync(request)
```

I am getting response code `OK` but not getting refresh token.

Comment: You mean you are getting HTTP Response 200/202 but what exact response object is returned back ? Have you parsed it ? Please check the section "Salesforce Server Sends a Response"  of the link you have shared.

Comment: I parsed it but there is no property like access token

Answer (score 0):

I think some SalesForce configurations do not come with the refreshtoken values out of the box. So if you want to avoid getting new tokens for every call, you could implement your own version of the refresh token. For instance set a Date -"expiryDate" in your code, which would be a date in the future. For every Rest call to SalesForce, check if today's date exceeds/is later than "expiryDate". If it does, request a new accesstoken. Else you could just keep on using the connection with the same accesstoken. THe challenge however, is of course when the real token expires. But I guess if there is no information about when the token expires in the accesstoken response, will it ever expire?

Answer (score 0):

`grant_type = refresh_token` is for exchanging a *previously* issued refresh token for a new access token. To obtain a refresh token, you have to go through an oAuth flow (aka grant type) that issues it. The flow you want depends on your application; authorization code grant (aka [Web Server](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&type=5) flow in Salesforce docs) is a frequent and recommended option.